# Creating XML file representing folder structure (including subfolders) in C#

Tags: c#, xml, directory

How can  produce an XML file structuring a given folder to recursively represent all the files & subfolders within it?

Comment: You'll need to prove that you tried something so far!

Comment: Please provide some example of what you have tried. Preferably also provide an example of the kind of output you are expecting. If you can't provide a complete example then show what you can do (for instance if you don't know how to enumerate a directory then abstract that away)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's great example of problem, that can be easily solved using recursive algorithm!

Pseudo-code:

```
function GetDirectoryXml(path)
    xml := "<dir name='" + path + "'>"

    dirInfo := GetDirectoryInfo(path)
    for each file in dirInfo.Files
        xml += "<file name='" + file.Name + "' />"
    end for

    for each subDir in dirInfo.Directories
        xml += GetDirectoryXml(subDir.Path)
    end for

    xml += "</dir>"

    return xml
end function
```

It can be done with C# and [`DirectoryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s2fzb02.aspx)/`XDocument`/`XElement` classes like that:

```
public static XElement GetDirectoryXml(DirectoryInfo dir)
{
    var info = new XElement("dir",
                   new XAttribute("name", dir.Name));

    foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
        info.Add(new XElement("file",
                     new XAttribute("name", file.Name)));

    foreach (var subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
        info.Add(GetDirectoryXml(subDir));

    return info;
}
```

And example of usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string rootPath = Console.ReadLine();
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(rootPath);

    var doc = new XDocument(GetDirectoryXml(dir));

    Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());

    Console.Read();
}
```

Output for one of directories on my laptop:

```
<dir name="eBooks">
  <file name="Edulinq.pdf" />
  <file name="MCTS 70-516 Accessing Data with Microsoft NET Framework 4.pdf" />
  <dir name="Silverlight">
    <file name="Sams - Silverlight 4 Unleashed.pdf" />
    <file name="Silverlight 2 Unleashed.pdf" />
    <file name="WhatsNewInSilverlight4.pdf" />
  </dir>
  <dir name="Windows Phone">
    <file name="11180349_Building_Windows_Phone_Apps_-_A_Developers_Guide_v7_NoCover (1).pdf" />
    <file name="Programming Windows Phone 7.pdf" />
  </dir>
  <dir name="WPF">
    <file name="Building Enterprise Applications with WPF and the MVVM Pattern (pdf).pdf" />
    <file name="Prism4.pdf" />
    <file name="WPF Binding CheatSheet.pdf" />
  </dir>
</dir>
```

Comment: Sorry to ask guys, but I'm looking to do something similar to this to generate an XML (or other jQuery-accessable filetype). The XML (or other) document that outputs the directories and their contents will be parsed and used to make a music player.

I'm an ASP Classic guy (just getting into .NET) and am curious- If I were to start with the code above, what type of file could I use? .aspx? Is their anyway to do this in ASP.NET Web Pages?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to know what's the problem you are having.

You'll need to use [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles.aspx) and [DirectoryInfo.GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s7xk2b58.aspx) to get the list of files and folder, loop with recursion. Then use the Xml.XmlDocument to write the [xml document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx).

Comment: It would be much easier to achieve using `XDocument` then `XmlDocument`