# Form a tree of files and folders

Tags: c#, recursion, datatable, tree, treeview

How can I recursively get all folders and files tree from folder? I need to put this tree into DataTable and form a treeView from it. I have a little problem with forming recursion methods, for now I only have a draft which doesn't work properly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace SWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private int id, parentID;
        private List<TREE> tree;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            tree = new List<TREE>();
            id = 0;
            parentID = 0;

            fill(@"D:\c#");
        }

        private List<TREE> fill(string path)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
            foreach (DirectoryInfo folder in dir.GetDirectories())
            {
                tree.Add(new TREE(){ID = id++, ParentID = parentID++, Name = folder.Name, Type = "Folder"});

                foreach (FileInfo file in folder.GetFiles())
                {
                    tree.Add(new TREE() { ID = id, ParentID = parentID, Name = file.Name, Type = "File" });  
                }
                var p = folder.GetDirectories();
                if (p.Length > 0)
                {
                    dir = folder;
                    fill(dir.FullName);
                }
            }
            return tree;
        }
    }

public class TREE
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Type {get;set;}
}

}
```

Please, could you show me right way forming and putting tree into DataTable. List is good, but I need DataTable.

I tried this, but it doesn't want to work properly:

```
public DataTable fill(DirectoryInfo dir)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Tasks");

            //dt.Columns.Add("ID");
            dt.Columns.Add("ParentID");
            dt.Columns.Add("Name");
            dt.Columns.Add("Type");

            foreach (var folder in dir.GetDirectories())
            {
                var row = dt.NewRow();

                row["ParentID"] = folder.Parent;
                row["Name"] = folder.Name;
                row["Type"] = "dir";
                dt.Rows.Add(row);

                foreach (var file in folder.GetFiles())
                {
                    var row2 = dt.NewRow();

                    row["ParentID"] = folder.Parent;
                    row["Name"] = file.Name;
                    row["Type"] = "file";
                    dt.Rows.Add(row2);
                }

                fill(folder);
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a0046c9e-3857-4208-93d1-2e7a4249eb25/bind-treeview-to-datatable Shows one way to do it and has links to alternative approaches.

Comment: One more option would be constructing Xml hierarchy. Refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15096397/creating-xml-file-representing-folder-structure-including-subfolders-in-c-shar , and using ReadXml method of datatable.

Comment: DataTable serialize perfectly, I need to send it via WCF service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd implement the recursive part:

```
static class IdGenerator
{
    static int _id = 1;
    public static int Generate() { return _id++; }
}

class Tree
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Tree Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<string> Files { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tree> Trees { get; set; }

    internal Tree ()
    {
        Id = IdGenerator.Generate();
        Name = String.Empty;
        ParentId = 0;
        Parent = null;
        Files = new List<string>();
        Trees = new List<Tree>();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Join("\n", new[] { Id + "\t" + Path.Combine(Parent != null ? Parent.Name : String.Empty, Name) }.Union(Files).Union(Trees.Select(t => t.ToString()))) + "\n";
    }

    public static Tree CreateTree(string path, Tree parent, string pattern)
    {
        try
        {
            var tree = new Tree
            {
                Parent = parent,
                ParentId = parent != null ? parent.Id : 0,
                Name = Path.GetFileName(path),
                Files = Directory.GetFiles(path, pattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)).ToArray(),
            };
            tree.Trees = Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).Select(d => CreateTree(d, tree, pattern)).ToArray();

            return tree;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
        { return new Tree(); }
    }
}
```

If I were to continue with this, I'd use [**Entity Framework Code First**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx) to generate the database from the POCO `Tree`, and drop the static `IdGenerator` since EF would generate these database IDs for me.

**EDIT**

However, here's how to do it in a DataTable:

```
class TreeDataTable : DataTable
{
    public TreeDataTable()
        : this("trees")
    {
    }

    public TreeDataTable(string tableName)
        : base(tableName)
    {
        Columns.Add("Id");
        Columns.Add("Name");
        Columns.Add("ParentId");
        Columns.Add("Type");
    }

    public void AddFile(int id, string name, int parent)
    {
        AddRow(id, name, parent, typeof(FileInfo));
    }

    public void AddTree(Tree tree)
    {
        AddRow(tree.Id, tree.Name, tree.ParentId, typeof(DirectoryInfo));
        var table = tree.ToDataTable();
        foreach (var r in table.Rows.Cast<DataRow>())
            AddRow(Convert.ToInt32(r["Id"]), r["Name"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(r["ParentId"]), Type.GetType(r["Type"].ToString()));
    }

    public string ToXml()
    {
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (var tw = new XmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                tw.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

                tw.WriteStartDocument();
                tw.WriteStartElement(TableName);

                ((IXmlSerializable)this).WriteXml(tw);

                tw.WriteEndElement();
                tw.WriteEndDocument();

            }

            return sw.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void AddRow(int id, string name, int parent, Type type)
    {
        var row = NewRow();
        row["Id"] = id;
        row["Name"] = name;
        row["ParentId"] = parent;
        row["Type"] = type.ToString();

        Rows.Add(row);
    }
}
```

And add this method to `Tree`:

```
    public DataTable ToDataTable()
    {
        var table = new TreeDataTable();

        foreach (var f in Files)
            table.AddFile(IdGenerator.Generate(), f, Id);
        foreach (var t in Trees)
            table.AddTree(t);

        return table;
    }
```

Here's how to use it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var path = args.FirstOrDefault(a => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(a)) ?? @"C:\Documents\Videos";
        args = args.Skip(1).ToArray();
        var pattern = args.FirstOrDefault(a => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(a)) ?? "*.mp4";
        var tree = Tree.CreateTree(path, null, pattern);

        Console.WriteLine((tree.ToDataTable() as TreeDataTable).ToXml());
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, I'll try to understand this. However, I'd like something simple like this [question has been updated].

Comment: Your question said "How can I recursively get all folders and files tree from folder?" and "I have a little problem with forming recursion methods". This answers that.

Comment: I know, but it's so damn hard way to do a simple task, no offence.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll use this as dll.

Comment: How to bind this DataTable to TreeView item in WPF?